# javascript and asp.net web user controls

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, web-user-controls

I have a web user control that generates the following html on the client.

I want to reference a specific RadioButton control using JavaScript.

I am not sure how to do this as the RadioButton ID is generated by asp.net.

For example I give the RadioButton ID = `1_RadioButton`

asp.net generates an ID = `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_1_RadioButton`

how can this javascript code find  Radio Button controls?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (document.getElementById("1_RadioButton").checked) {
                $("#1_other").hide();
            }
        });    
    </script>
```

The following is what asp.net generates for the client.

```
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_1_RadioButton" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Material$Academic" value="1_RadioButton" onclick="javascript:$('#1_other').show('fast');" />

    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_1_RadioButton">Yes</label>

    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_2_RadioButton" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Material$Academic" value="2_RadioButton" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:$('#1_other').hide('fast');" />

    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_2_RadioButton">No</label>

    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_3_RadioButton" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Material$Academic" value="3_RadioButton" onclick="javascript:$('#1_other').hide('fast');" />

    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_3_RadioButton">Uncertain</label>

    <div id='1_other'>
         <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Material$4_TextBox" type="text" value="bbb chabng" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Material_4_TextBox" />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that code is in the .aspx file use <%= MyRadioButton.ClientID %> in its place and the ASP.NET rendering engine will properly render the ID for you.

**Update:** For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($get("<%= MyRadioButton.ClientID %>").checked) {
            $("#1_other").hide();
        }
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks...

I am getting a 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required'
some I must be doing something else wrong.  

I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: My issue was that I was dynamically creating these controls.  When I generate the javascript needed to do a find/replace with the Control.ID with the Control.ClientID.  All works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var radioButton = document.getElementById("<%= 1_RadioButton.ClientID %>");
```

And then go from there. Note - I'm not positive about the quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

I had written a [blog post on how to do this](http://ralphwhitbeck.com/2009/01/31/SelectingAASPNETGeneratedIDWithJQuery.aspx):

> So say you have a label control on
>   your page:
>
> The generated output of the html and
>   the ID of that control might look like
>   this:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1"></span>
```

> Unfortunately the generated ID of
>   ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1 isn't
>   always going to be the same from build
>   to build.  So trying to select it like
>   this:
>
> `$("#ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1").hide();`
>
> will eventually break and it won't
>   hide the label control.
>
> The trick is to use ASP.NET inside the
>   jQuery selector. Label1.ClientID will
>   return the generated ID everytime. We
>   combine ASP.NET and jQuery into one
>   line like this:
>
> `$("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").hide();`
>
> This will get the generated ID of the
>   Label control everytime.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple just set the `clientidmode` of the web control to static (`clientidmode="static"`) and you can be sure that `asp.net` will keep your `ID` as seen in the designer UI.

Comment: But, the problem here is ClientIDMode is available from .NET 4. What to do if we use .NET 3.5.

Comment: This also presents the possible problem of allowing duplicate control names.  If you're using any technologies other than "pure" aspx pages, such as web controls, master pages, etc (and you probably should be) then you run the risk of control ID's being duplicated and causing unpredictable behavior.  This can be especially true if multiple developers are working on different components.