# Modal Dialog Box - return value not always returned

Tags: asp.net

Could you please help me?
I've created a Modal Dialog Box based on the code shown in this article:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/javascript_modal_dialog.asp

In my sample code, I use this dialog three times: for a hyperlink, a button Button1 with the onclick attribute added and a button Button2 with the OnClientClick event.
If I click the hyperlink, the return value from the dialog box that defines the dialog's button being clicked goes to a text box.
But if I click either Button1 or Button2, I cannot get the return value, i.e. determine which of the dialog's buttons gets clicked.

Could you please help me find a correct way to get the dialog's return value? 
I'm especially interested in the case of Button1 with the onclick attribute added.

Below is my Page and code-behind test code.

== Page ==

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ModalDialogTest1.aspx.vb" Inherits="ModalDialogTest1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script language="javascript">

var ModalDialogWindow;
var ModalDialogInterval;
var ModalDialog = new Object;

ModalDialog.value = '';
ModalDialog.eventhandler = '';


function ModalDialogMaintainFocus()
{
  try
  {
    if (ModalDialogWindow.closed)
     {
        window.clearInterval(ModalDialogInterval);
        eval(ModalDialog.eventhandler);       
        return;
     }
    ModalDialogWindow.focus(); 
  }
  catch (everything) {   }
}

 function ModalDialogRemoveWatch()
 {
    ModalDialog.value = '';
    ModalDialog.eventhandler = '';
 }

 function ModalDialogShow(Title,BodyText,Buttons,EventHandler)
 {

   ModalDialogRemoveWatch();
   ModalDialog.eventhandler = EventHandler;

   var args='width=350,height=125,left=325,top=300,toolbar=0,';
       args+='location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0';  

   ModalDialogWindow=window.open("","",args); 
   ModalDialogWindow.document.open(); 
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<html>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<head>'); 
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<title>' + Title + '</title>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<script' + ' language=JavaScript>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('function CloseForm(Response) ');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('{ ');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write(' window.opener.ModalDialog.value = Response; ');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write(' window.close(); ');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('} ');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('</script' + '>');        
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('</head>');   
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<body onblur="window.focus();">');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<table border=0 width="95%" align=center cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<tr><td align=left>' + BodyText + '</td></tr>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<tr><td align=left><br></td></tr>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('<tr><td align=center>' + Buttons + '</td></tr>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('</body>');
   ModalDialogWindow.document.write('</html>'); 
   ModalDialogWindow.document.close(); 
   ModalDialogWindow.focus(); 
   ModalDialogInterval = window.setInterval("ModalDialogMaintainFocus()",5);

 }

</script>

<script language=JavaScript>
    function OKCancel_1(BodyText, EventHandler) {
        var Buttons = '';
        Buttons = '<input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="butt" style="width:100px;" onclick=javascript:CloseForm("Cancel");>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        Buttons += '<input type="submit" value="OK" class="butt" style="width:100px;" onclick=javascript:CloseForm("OK");>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        ModalDialogShow("Dialog", BodyText, Buttons, EventHandler);
    }

    function NoYes(BodyText, EventHandler) {
        var Buttons = '';
        Buttons = '<input type="submit" value="No" class="butt" style="width:100px;" onclick=javascript:CloseForm("No");>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        Buttons += '<input type="submit" value="Yes" class="butt" style="width:100px;" onclick=javascript:CloseForm("Yes");>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        ModalDialogShow("Dialog", BodyText, Buttons, EventHandler);
    }

  function OKCancelReturnMethod() {
    document.getElementById('OKCancelReturn').value = ModalDialog.value;
    ModalDialogRemoveWatch();
  }

  function NoYesReturnMethod() {
    document.getElementById('modalreturn').value = ModalDialog.value;
    ModalDialogRemoveWatch();
  }

</script>

<body>


<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server"
         NavigateUrl="javascript:OKCancel_1('OKCancel test','OKCancelReturnMethod()');">OK/Cancel_1
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="OKCancelReturn:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="OKCancelReturn" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button -> NoYes onclick" >
        </asp:Button>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button -> NoYes OnClientClick" 
         OnClientClick="javascript:NoYes('NoYes test','NoYesReturnMethod()');">
        </asp:Button>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="modalreturn:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="modalreturn" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

== code-behind===

```
Partial Class ModalDialogTest1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim message As String
        message = "Test Message: Do you want to delete?"
        Button1.Attributes("onclick") = GetConfirmationScript(message)
     End Sub

    Private Function GetConfirmationScript(ByVal message As String) As String
        Dim output As String
        output = "javascript:NoYes('" & message & "','NoYesReturnMethod()');"
        Return output
    End Function

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OKCancelReturn.Text = modalreturn.Text

    End Sub
End Class
```

Many thanks,
Lev

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have two NoYesReturnMethods, and pass a different one in onclick of Button1 and Button2.

```
OnClientClick="NoYes('NoYes test','NoYesReturnMethod1()')
```

(and similarly for button2 -> NoYesReturnMethod2.)

However this is probably not what you want to hear, but the code you've based this on is diabolically terrible. It's much more complicated than it needs to be and abuses `eval`, `javascript:` URLs, unescaped HTML string-bodging, chromeless popups, and discarding exceptions... it's like a grab bag of worst possible practices.

If all your cases are simply a message with yes/no buttons you would be better off sticking with a trivial `window.confirm` call. If you might need to include more involved dialogue-forms, try one of the many other in-page-dialogue-box scripts/plugins.

Comment: Bobince, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, having two different methods doesn't help: neither method returns a value. So again: if I use a hyperlink to call the Modal Dialog, it works, if I use buttons - doesn't. More thoughts? As for your note, the reason of not using a trivial window.confirm call is that the the dialog's default button is OK. My users needs the default button to be Cancel. That's why I try to deal with a custom dialog. Looking forward to your answer. Thanks, Lev

Comment: It does return the value; I think it's just the (debugging?) attempt to write it to `document.getElementById('modalreturn').value` that is failing. You can't use ASP.NET IDs as page element IDs verbatim because ASP.NET changes them to `ct100-something-modalreturn` and similar to avoid name clashes. You have to start sticking ugly `<%= modalreturn.ClientID %>` ASP in your JS if you want to do it like this. See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836121/javascript-and-asp-net-web-user-controls